# Enabling default popup template not working in ArcGIS Maps SDK JS

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

When adding the feature layer with URL, enabling defaultPopUpTemplate does not open any pop-up. When I click on the feature the feature gets highlighted however, nothing opens up.

I am attaching the code:

```
    require(["esri/config", "esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"], function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, FeatureLayer){
    
    esriConfig.apiKey = ""

    var map = new Map({
        basemap: "arcgis-topographic"
    });

    var view = new MapView({
        map: map,
        center: [77.18108, 28.53337],
        zoom: 15,
        container: "viewDiv"
    })

    view.popup.defaultPopupTemplateEnabled = true;

    const floralayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: "XXXXXXX",
    });

    map.add(floralayer)
    
    });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It should work. Without your actual feature layer it's impossible to say why it does not work for you. Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section?

Comment: I have tried with a service from sample server 6, still facing the same issue, I guess there is something that I am missing.

Comment: Which version of JS SDK are you using?

Comment: See simple JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/sjancrf2/. Works without problems.

Comment: I am using 4.27, this looks good however, can you try adding feature service instead of map service and then check. I tried replacing the URL present in JS Fiddle with this, https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/CommunityAddressing/FeatureServer/0, however, the features are not loading.

Comment: Isn't `const states = new FeatureLayer({url: "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/2", ...` a feature service?